# JS- Change element class/id based on parent element class

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm want to change the class of a child element class based on the parent element class.

For example

```
<div class="change">
    <div class="show-more"></div>
</div>
```

If parent class is `class="change"` then change the child class to `class="show-none"`

```
<div class="change">
    <div class="show-none"></div>
</div>
```

And how can I also do this to change the child id for example

```
<div class="change">
    <div id="show-more"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="change">
    <div id="show-none"></div>
</div>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS selectors and the classlist property.

If you want to do this for one element:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.change .show-more')
el.classList.remove('show-more')
el.classList.add('show-none')
```

If you want to do this for all the elements that match this selector:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.change .show-more').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('.show-more')
    el.classList.add('show-none')
})
```

Comment: thanks, what if I need to change an id instead of class?

Comment: You can use `#show-more` instead.

[Here's a list of CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript

```html
<div class="change">
    <div class="show-more"></div>
</div>

<script>
    const allParentElement = document.getElementsByClassName('change');
    const child = document.querySelector('.show-more');

    for (const parentElement of allParentElement) {
        if (parentElement.contains(child)) {
            child.classList.add('show-none');
            child.classList.remove('show-more');
        }
    }
</script>
```